# using functions in a php file through URL rewrited by htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a php file with a function **add_user** inside it.

I want to call that fuction from my browser, and it works if I use the URL    `user.php?rquest=add_user`, but I want to access the same function (and others in the same file too) with the following URL `user/add_function`.

Within an .htaccess file in the same directory I have the following rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^user/(.*)$ user.php?rquest=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

But I get a 404 error.

Apparently it doesnt like the `^user/` part, I think. Maybe because it is actually a file.

How can I access the **add_user** function using `user/add_user`?

Thank you.

Comment: In which folder is your htaccess file and what is the url your trying to connect to?

Comment: My htaccess file is inside `http://www.example.com/area/rest/` directory and I'm trying to access `http://www.example.com/area/rest/user.php` file **add_user** function using the following address `http://www.example.com/area/rest/user/add_user`

Comment: Add a RewriteBase directive : `RewriteBase /area/rest/` bellow the `RewriteEngine On` line .

Comment: It still doesn't work, I get the error **Not Found

The requested URL /area/rest/user/add_user was not found on this server.** when I try to access the function via `http://www.example.com/area/rest/user/add_user`

Comment: Perhaps `mod_rewrite` is not enabled? Is `AllowOverride` set to `All` in your server configuration?

Comment: @MikeRockett I contacted my hosting provider, they say that Mod_Rewrite is enabled but AllowOverride is restricted to some directives for security reasons. So I think `AllowOverride All` is not enabled. Is there anything I can do to accomplish what I want without the use of AllowOverride All?

Comment: Well, if `mod_rewrite` is enabled, and `AllowOverride` is allowing the use of `mod_rewrite` in `.htaccess` files, then it should be working. They're going to need to figure it out for you...

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by adding `Options -MultiViews` in my .htaccess file in that subdirectory.

I still think it's hosting provider related though.